# Ember invoke jQuery code only on initial render

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember component class, I want to run some jQuery code to hide some elements. However, I want this code to run only on initial render and not on other events (say grid refresh)

```
hidePositionElements: function() {
    var self = this;
    var currPosLabelElements = $( ".my-grid-footer-value");
    currPosLabelElements.hide();
},
```

I tried adding to "didRender", but that runs multiple times.

Also tried calling above function from "didInsertElement" hook, but jQuery is unable to find the elements at that stage.

Comment: `didInsertElement` should work. If not something else is wrong. Or use the `did-insert` modifier in newer ember versions.

Comment: an https://ember-twiddle.com/ repro would be nice to debug

Answer (score 2):

If the elements can’t be found on `didInsertElement()`, then you can try running the jQuery code after a short delay, for example

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component'
import { later } from '@ember/runloop';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    didInsertElement() {
        later(function () {
            $( ".my-grid-footer-value").hide();
        });
    }
}
```

The [`later()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.19/functions/@ember%2Frunloop/later) here is like `setTimeout()` but it runs in the [Ember runloop](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/run-loop/). And since no delay is  specified this should run as soon as possible (hopefully your grid footer elements will exist by the time it executes).

As a general rule, whenever you’re doing any DOM manipulation you should wrap it in a runloop method (usually [`run()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.19/functions/@ember%2Frunloop/run)) so that Ember can schedule the code to run at the right time.

However, as an Ember best practice *you should try and avoid modifying the DOM yourself* and instead let Ember handle it (using something like `{{#if this.showPositionElements}} ... {{/if}}` and then toggling `showPositionElements`).